# How to implement security in Spring Cloud API Gateway with Key Cloak for Multi-tenant Application

Tags: keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working on a project in which there is a requirement to convert single tenant application to multi tenant application. How to implement Multi-tenant support for Gateway using key cloak with spring security oauth2?
Any references please share

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository to register your clients dynamically at runtime. You can then plug this implementation to a custom Webfilter, which will use your custom repository to compute the client details based on the logged in user's realm(which can be the hostname, email etc.)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TenantClientRegistrationRepository implements ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository {
  
  private final Map<String, String> tenants = new HashMap<>();
  
  private final Map<String, Mono<ClientRegistration>> clients = new HashMap<>();

  public TenantClientRegistrationRepository() {
      this.tenants.put("tenant1", "http://localhost:8080/realms/tenant1");
      this.tenants.put("tenant2", "http://localhost:8080/realms/tenant2");
      
      
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<ClientRegistration> findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
      return this.clients.computeIfAbsent(registrationId, this::fromTenant);
  }

  private Mono<ClientRegistration> fromTenant(String registrationId) {
      return Optional.ofNullable(this.tenants.get(registrationId))
              .map(uri -> Mono.defer(() -> clientRegistration(uri, registrationId)).cache())
              .orElse(Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("unknown tenant")));
  }

  private Mono<ClientRegistration> clientRegistration(String uri, String registrationId) {
      return Mono.just(ClientRegistrations.fromIssuerLocation(uri)
              .registrationId(registrationId)
              .clientId("web-client")//fetch client creds via rest or some other means
              .clientSecret("********")
              .scope("openid")
              .build());
  }

  @KafkaListener(topics="tenants")
  //TODO: Here we will populate tenants(realm) and respective client details based on tenant creation event
  public void action(Map<String, Map<String, Object>> action) {
      if (action.containsKey("created")) {
          Map<String, Object> tenant = action.get("created");
          String alias = (String) tenant.get("alias");
          String issuerUri = (String) tenant.get("issuerUri");
          this.tenants.put(alias, issuerUri);
          this.clients.remove(alias);
      }
  }
}
```

```
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.web.server.logout.OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.util.context.Context;

public class TenantFilterChain implements WebFilter, ApplicationContextAware {
    private final Map<String, Mono<WebFilter>> tenants = new HashMap<>();
    private final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clients;
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public TenantFilterChain(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        Mono<ClientRegistration> tenant = toTenant(exchange);
        Mono<WebFilter> filter = tenant.flatMap(this::fromTenant);

        return Mono.zip(tenant, filter)
                .flatMap(tuple -> tuple.getT2().filter(exchange, chain)
                        .contextWrite(Context.of(ClientRegistration.class, tuple.getT1()))
                        .thenReturn(exchange))
                .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange).thenReturn(exchange))
                .then(Mono.empty());
    }

    private Mono<ClientRegistration> toTenant(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        String host = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI())
                .build().getHost();
        return this.clients.findByRegistrationId(host);
    }

    private Mono<WebFilter> fromTenant(ClientRegistration registration) {
        return this.tenants.computeIfAbsent(registration.getRegistrationId(), tenant -> {
            ServerHttpSecurity http = new ContextAwareServerHttpSecurity(this.context);

            OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler handler =
                    new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clients);
            handler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:8282");

            ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint =
                    new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/" + tenant);

            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeExchange(e -> e
                    .pathMatchers("/jwks").permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .logout(l -> l.logoutSuccessHandler(handler))
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint));
            // @formatter:on

            return Mono.just((WebFilter) new WebFilterChainProxy(http.build())).cache();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private static class ContextAwareServerHttpSecurity extends ServerHttpSecurity {
        ContextAwareServerHttpSecurity(ApplicationContext context) {
            super.setApplicationContext(context);
        }
    }
}
```

[Referenced codebase](https://github.com/jzheaux/springone2019)

[Talk by Josh Cummings on multitenancy with spring security OAuth2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke13w8nab-k)

Hope this helps !! :)